Replies with SVG + JavaScript and DOM: Comment (and Request)
In some of my replies to questions at Stack Exchange sites I would like to add SVG images with related JavaScript codes because the replies were meant to be interactive. In lieu of this lack of support I often add links to another site which includes PDF versions of my replies with related JavaScripts. In the PDF version I include attachments which include SVG versions of the reply with related JavaScripts.
If I can directly add my SVG+JavaScript as part of the reply then I would not have to go through all that trouble.
I think it would be useful to all users if they can to reply with SVG+JavaScript in their replies and if they can read replies with interactive SVGs. Please consider (or reconsider) providing SVG+JavaScript support in your sites. Thanks!

If you’re looking for this level of interactivity, I’m not sure comments are the right tool. They’re supposed to be temporary Post-it notes more than fully fledged responses.

If you're talking about answers, rather than comments, please [edit] your question to explain why the existing Stack Snippet capability is not sufficient.

Your title saying "Comment (and Request)" make it less clear as to if you are talking about having this content in answers or comments. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

It's already requested to allow SVG upload, which also includes the "full" versions with JS and all.

I sometimes post SVG diagrams, including anims, eg https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125819/36040 I don't know if it would be wise to permit fully interactive SVG with JavaScript, though.
